# Oracle's DBMS_CRYPTO.DES_CBC_PKCS equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, cryptography

I need to rewrite one package to C# and Im stucked with this cryptography function

```
     l_DEcrypted :=    dbms_crypto.DEcrypt
                   ( src => l_ssn,
                     typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.DES_CBC_PKCS5,
                     key => G_KEY );
```

Any ideas, how to write code with same output in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- DES: [DESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
- CBC: [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode.aspx) = [CipherMode.CBC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx)
- PKCS5: [Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding.aspx) = [PaddingMode.PKCS7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode.aspx)

Comment: When I have this key used in Oracle, how can I put it to c#?

G_KEY RAW(320) := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW( 'xxx xxx xx xxx xxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'AL32UTF8' ); 

C# is complaining about key size, which is for DES 64 bits.